# Recursion Error using pyqtgraph with PySide6

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, pyside6

I am having trouble implementing pyqtgraph with PySide6. I have used pyqtgraph with PyQt5 without a hitch, but I'm making a new application in PySide6 specifically for a new project.

I checked the pyqtgraph documentation and it says to import your Qt wrapper before pyqtgraph so it knows which to work with.

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QTabWidget

from gui_scripts.tab_plot import PlotTab
import PySide6
import pyqtgraph as pg

from __feature__ import snake_case, true_property


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.graph_widget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.set_central_widget(self.graph_widget)
        hour = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        temperature = [30, 32, 34, 32, 33, 31, 29, 32, 35, 45]
        self.graph_widget.plot(hour, temperature)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I get a "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object" triggered where self.graph_widget = pg.PlotWidget()

I used this example https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyside-plotting-pyqtgraph/ to generate the same error because my actual implementation is across a few scripts. The application has a navigation tab that switches between a few interfaces, one of which will be a plot, and the code worked just fine until I added the tab for the plot.

Edit:
The code is fine when I don't import the class from tab_plot. That script is

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QGridLayout
import sys
import pyqtgraph as pg

from __feature__ import snake_case, true_property


class PlotTab(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')
        pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')

        self.parent = parent

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.plot1 = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.plot1.setLabel('left', 'Temperature (K)')
        self.plot1.setLabel('bottom', 'Voltage (V)')
        self.layout.add_widget(self.plot1, 0, 0)
```

Edit2:
this is the error happening at:
self.plot1 = pg.PlotWidget()
File "..\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\widgets\PlotWidget.py", line 51, in **init**
GraphicsView.**init**(self, parent, background=background)

File "..\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\widgets\GraphicsView.py", line 73, in **init**
self.useOpenGL(useOpenGL)

File "..\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\widgets\GraphicsView.py", line 168, in useOpenGL
self.setViewport(v)

File "..\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\widgets\PlotWidget.py", line 78, in **getattr**
if hasattr(self.plotItem, attr):

File ..\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\widgets\PlotWidget.py", line 78, in **getattr**
if hasattr(self.plotItem, attr):

File "..\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\widgets\PlotWidget.py", line 78, in **getattr**
if hasattr(self.plotItem, attr):
[Previous line repeated 988 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: For clarification, if I remove the snake_case feature, and rename the methods to camelCase, I get the same error.

Comment: Is the code above *exactly* the script you're running? Try to make it *completely* minimal: remove the `plot()` line and the unnecessary imports. Also, try to run the program in a terminal or prompt to get a more useful traceback.

Comment: @musicamante When I remove the "from gui_scripts.tab_plot import PlotTab" line, it corrects itself, but the error is stated to be in the line where the plot widget is created in MainWindow. Which is very confusing

Comment: I think I may need to remake this whole post

Comment: Keep this in mind for future reference, as that's one of the many reasons for which it's almost always mandatory to create a MRE. If you tried to make the code as minimal as possible, you'd have probably found out the source of problem on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. pyqtgraph is not compatible with the snake_case feature from PySide6. I thought removing it didn't have an impact, but it was still importing a script that was using it.

Comment: I for one (but I know I'm not alone) have **always** been against the snake_case feature (and to some measure, the `=` property), as I felt it was extremely inconsistent, confusing and prone to bugs and issues. We see periodically some questions or bugs that pop out due to this, and I sincerely hope that sooner or later they will finally drop this completely unnecessary abomination, as it's something that absolutely nobody (in their rightful minds) really needed or would have asked, and there is absolutely ***no*** reason that is good enough for it (including PEP8).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `super(MainWindow, self).__init__()` after `def __init__(self):`

It works fine for me like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)

        hour = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
        temperature = [30, 32, 34, 32, 33, 31, 29, 32, 35, 45]

        # plot data: x, y values
        self.graphWidget.plot(hour, temperature)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MainWindow()
w.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but QMainWindow.__init__(self) accomplishes the same thing. I just used your line instead to confirm, but it raises the same error.

Comment: I believe the recursion error has nothing to do with this part of the code, but rather the data it is calling.  Can you share an example of the code that is feeding the data for the graph? You can check your recursion limit with `print(sys(getrecursionlimit())` and we can probably avoid the recursion with a loop if I had some insight on how this recursion is taking place.

Comment: Same error happens with this. I'll edit the post with the exact error

Comment: still not enough information to be helpful, I'm sorry.  If it's not a recursion from calling data, than maybe it's a recursion error from a infinite loop from both scripts trying to do the same thing or calling something that loops back to itself?  Sorry I wish I could help more.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and found the answer: update your pyqtgraph's version

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).